# Rails SQL select, doesn't seem to work as expected with the CASE statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to understand how to use the select method in queries to return custom columns.

I'm running Rails 5.2, database is postgresql.

```sql
m = Message.all.select("messages.*, CASE WHEN id > 30 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS above_30")
```

returns only the messages table with all its columns. How do I get the `above_30` column, preferable eager loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `above_30` is there, but Rails will not define an access for it because there is no column by that name in your schema.

You can define one yourself, or use `m[:above_30]` to access the "raw" attributes of the object as returned from the query.

Comment: Yes this works. Thanks. I have another question, that hopefully you can answer. I tried the above statement with includes to eager load all associations, like so: `m= Message.all.select("messages.*, CASE WHEN id > 30 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS above_30").includes(:user)` This resulted in 2 SQL statements. The first one was expected, a message load getting all the Message type objects. But the second one is a User load, like so `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)` Can you please explain what's going on here?

Comment: @kchak That's what eager-loading does. Two queries instead of N+1, where N is the number of associated records. It loads all the `users` in a single query by taking the distinct set of user IDs in the returned messages, and querying for those users.